# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Element]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.- ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I'm converting a html string to React element using the DOM parser and render it in my component.

**I'm unable to use the dangerouslySetElements method as we are using sanitize html to encode any html tags and hence this usage render raw html with tags.**

code:

```
function() {
const element = (
<div>
   <span>test232></span>
   <label>ahddgd</label>
</div>
}
<span data-tip-react data-tip = {ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)}>test</span>

    test() {
           let section;
           tipValue = targetNode.getAttribute("data-tip");
           const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(tipValue, "text/xml");
           section = (doc.childNodes[0]);
    }
```

and this is the o/p I get for `section`:
[image]

now when I try to render this in my component, it throws this error:

```
render() {
  return (
      <div>{section}</div>
  )
}

Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Element]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Any idea how to convert the above o.p that would render as react comp.? Unfortunately im also unable to use any third party lib..:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but it is not recommended.

From the docs:

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it’s dangerous.

Here is a working example how this could be done:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App(){
  const [data, setData] = useState("Loading...");
  useEffect(()=>{
    const containerInnerHTML = document.querySelector('#element').innerHTML;   
    setData(containerInnerHTML);    
  },[]);
  
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}}/>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>


<div id="element">
  <div>node 1</div>
  <div>node 2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank @miroslav for your answer, however I just found out that we are using sanitize to encode any html tags and hence if I use dangerouslysetelemets, it will render raw html with tags...:(

Comment: @user1234 You could pass it raw and sanitize it on the front end possibly using [sanitize-html-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-html-react) or unescape the sanitzed HTML using something like [unescape](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unescape). Not exactly sure of your use cases so these may be non-ideal. What I would recommend is passing the data down as an object or array and build your elements using that data directly in React.

Comment: This is the way we are sinitizing using dompurify- ```<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sanitize(tipValue)}}/>``` ```const sanitize = (text) => {
  return escape(dompurify.sanitize(text));
};```

Comment: I tried the second approach your recommendation of using the data in react comp, however in that case I'll be restricting the html structure to a particular one and wont be able to pass any dynamic html structure to the component.

Comment: Is there something we can handle it suing plain JS? like: function/method?

Comment: @user1234 [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) perhaps?

Comment: Also, it not recommended to render out raw HTML, the components of the HTML structure should be defined in a way so you would be able to render out your data by just having the pieces.